# Disable Alt-key combinations for non ASCII characters

Tags: key-bindings

I use the Alt-Latin keyboard layout (set in OSX) to write diacritics in Vim. This layout uses combinations with the Alt and Shift keys for modified letters. For example `<A-.>` followed by a letter prints that letter with a dot below, e.g. `ḍ`. Now, in Vim, some of these combinations are overridden, so that in `<A-.>` prints `®`, for example. How can I disable these key combinations in Vim to get the combinations of the layout as defined in the OS.

---

This is a follow-up of a previous question (which I deleted) in which I wrongly assumed that this had something to do with `diagraphs`.

Comment: This looks more like a fault in the input system. Ideally, this keycode shouldn't sent to the application until you've either completed it (by pressing `.`) or aborted it (usually by pressing space). It also doesn't seem like it's Vim that prints `®` (there's no mapping for this by default), but rather the terminal or OS.